# How to return data using boolean field in Where clause using SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, reserved-words

I have a simple table which has the following data

[image]
from that table records I simply try to get record where `Primary` field is set to 1. For that I simply use the following:

```
select *
from ProductProductPhoto
where ProductId = 12
  and Primary = 1
```

But I get a syntax error reported by SQLite and have no reason why.

I have also try the query in following form :

```
select *
from ProductProductPhoto
where ProductId = 12
  and  Primary
```

but no luck, the error return in browser for SQLite tool is :

> "near "Primary": syntax error: "

Any idea how this syntax need to be ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`primary` is a [reserved word in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html), you should escape it with double quotes `"`:

```
select *
from "ProductProductPhoto"
where "ProductId" = 12
  and "Primary" = 1
```